# c# set focus on multiple child forms

Tags: c#, forms

I have a main form and then open one childdialog (nr 1) and on that I open an other childdialog (nr 2).

When I then open up that main form from another application the focus is set on the last child (nr 2), when I press enter the focus is set on the main form, I want the focus to go on child nr 1.

To open up the main form I use Activate();

Then in OwnedForms I have an array of children.

```
Activate();

if(OwnedForms.Any())
{
   OwnedForms.Last().Focus();
}
```

When I choose to close that form that has focus, the focus will go to the main form instead of the next child (last -1) in the OwnedForms array.

Tried bringtofront and sendtoback without any success.

Comment: A form does not have much use for the focus.  It doesn't interact with the user, doesn't show a focus rectangle, doesn't have built-in keyword behavior.  The user interacts with a control on the form, like a TextBox or Button.  If you want a form in the foreground and focus one of its controls then you have to Activate() it.

Comment: with the code I have now, I get the right focus. But its when I close that child that I get the focus on the main instead of the next child

Comment: If you leave it up to the OS to pick the next window to activate then you might well be disappointed about its choice.  Albeit that it often makes the sane choice, previous window that the user interacted with.  Surely you'll want to pay attention to its FormClosed event.  Do consider that you might be doing it wrong when you have to fight the machine, a UserControl tends to be the wise choice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the form's parent is set.

```
OwnedForms.Last().Parent =  this;
```

Also you may want to look into .Show()  vs .ShowDialog() on the forms.

It seems like you might prefer .ShowDialog() in your case if you are not already doing so.

Comment: The children is in the OwnedForms, with my code when I write Activate(); its on the parent form. I get the focus right on the child form, but its when I choose to close that child dialog that it goes to the parent, but I want it to go to the next last child.

Comment: Do you want the parent to ever be in focus when it has a child, or do you want to force them to resolve the child dialog(s) first before going back to the main form?